# shiny UI: `withMathJax()` within radioButton und checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny

Shiny delivers the `withMathJax()` function to display formulas in the UI.

I want to display some math wihtin checkbox and/or radiobutton options - but don`t get it to work.

Minimal example

```
require(shiny)
runApp(
  list(ui = pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel(withMathJax("$$\\text{Here it works }X_n=X_{n-1}-\\varepsilon$$")),

    sidebarPanel( radioButtons("test", withMathJax("$$\\text{Here it works too }X_n=X_{n-1}$$"),
                               choices = c(paste(withMathJax("$$\\text{Here it doesn`t work }X_n=X_{n-1}$$"), "= test"),
                                           "Rohe Skalierung"        = "raw",
                                           "Ueber alle Werte"        = "std",
                                           "Innerhalb der Personen" = "gstd"))),

    mainPanel( )
  ),
  server= function(input, output, session){

  }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Trial and error, inspired by the [corresponding RStudio shiny gallery example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/mathjax.html) leads me to the following solution:

```
require(shiny)
runApp(
  list(ui = pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel(withMathJax("$$\\text{Here it works }X_n=X_{n-1}-\\varepsilon$$")),

    sidebarPanel(withMathJax(), radioButtons("test",  "\\(X_n=X_{n-1}\\)",
                               choices = c("\\(X_n= \\text{And Here it works to }X_{n-1}\\)"      = "test",
                                           "Rohe Skalierung"         = "raw",
                                           "Ueber alle Werte"        = "std",
                                           "Innerhalb der Personen"  = "gstd"))),

    mainPanel( )
  ),
  server= function(input, output, session){

  }
  )
)
```